# Problems with includegraphics

Tags: graphics, floats, includegraphics

I'm using the [COLT 2019 style](https://learningtheory.org/colt2019/files/colt2019.zip), which is based on the JMLR style. Using `includegraphics` doesn't seem to work --- even when I use it exactly as in the JMLR manual (see the link above). The error I get says
`! Paragraph ended before \@tempa was complete.`
I've tried to include/exclude `graphicx`, but it remained as is. Any ideas?

Here is a minimal example:

```latex
\documentclass[anon,12pt]{colt2019}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title[Short Title]{Full Title of Article}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\floatconts
{fig:example}% label
{\caption{An Example Figure}}% caption command
{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{pic}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated (1) you can use one of the images from the `mwe` package (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe), then others also have that image, (2) the `times` package is clearly not related yto your issue.

Comment: You might want to list which version of LaTeX you are using, I'm using `LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3` (as listed at the top of the log file). My guess is that the redefinitions of `graphicx` internals done in `jmlr.cls` is not compatible with recent versions of `graphics`. You should probably report this to the COLT people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jmlr` class redefines internals of `graphicx` in a way that's incompatible with the most recent versions of the package.

For the time being, until the people responsible for the class fix the incompatibility, you can use a workaround:

```latex
\documentclass[anon]{colt2019}

\makeatletter
\let\Ginclude@graphics\@org@Ginclude@graphics
\makeatother

\title[Short Title]{Full Title of Article}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\begin{figure}[htbp]

\floatconts
  {fig:example}% label
  {\caption{An Example Figure}}% caption command
  {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Would you mind to elaborate a bit on this line in favor of my future education/others?